# Matching Data Tables by five columns to change a value in another column

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, data.table

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and run R in terminal.
I am working with big data tables, one has 75 millions rows and 11 columns (dt1) and another has 7 million rows and 7 columns (dt2). All values are numeric. Both tables have 'id' column'. I need to find all rows in the first one which have the same values for five columns as five columns in the second one, and change in the first data table 'id' value for these rows to the one in the second data table. In both data tables the compared columns have the same name, let us say that they are V1, V2, V3, V4 and V5. I've converted second data table to data frame format, so I can use its 'id' as index . I've tried it for 1000 first rows and it took 40 minutes.

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    dt1[(V1==dt2[i,V1] & V2==dt2[i,V2] &
         V3==dt2[i,V3] & V4==dt2[i,V4] &
         V5==dt2[i,V5]), id:=i]
}
```

I'm going to parallelize it, but due to memory constrictions I can use only 2 or 3 cores. Clearly it won't be sufficient. Are there quick and efficient ways to do it on my home comp? If to do it on AWS, what kind of tricks are useful there? In particular, how many cores may I use there simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R it is always preferable to avoid loops wherever possible, as they are usually much slower than alternative vectorized solutions.

This operation can be done with a data.table join. Basically, when you run

```
dt1[dt2];
```

you are performing a right-join between the two data.tables. The preset key columns of `dt1` determine which columns to join on. If `dt1` has no preset key, the operation fails. But you can specify the `on` argument to manually select the key columns on-the-fly:

```
key <- paste0('V',1:5);
dt1[dt2,on=key];
```

(The alternative of course is to preset a key, using either `setkey()` or `setkeyv()`.)

The above operation will actually just return a merged table containing data from both `dt1` and `dt2`, which is not what you want. But we can make use of the `j` argument of the data.table indexing function and the `:=` in-place assignment syntax to assign the `id` column of `dt2` to the `id` column of `dt1`. Because we have a name conflict, we must use `i.id` to reference the `id` column of `dt2`, while the unmodified name `id` still refers to the `id` column of `dt1`. This is simply the mechanism provided by data.table for disambiguating conflicting names. Hence, you're looking for:

```
dt1[dt2,on=key,id:=i.id];
```

Here's an example that uses only two key columns and just a few rows of data (for simplicity). I also generated the keys to include some non-matching rows, just to demonstrate that the non-matching rows will have their ids left untouched by the operation.

```
set.seed(1L);
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:12,expand.grid(V1=1:3,V2=1:4),blah1=rnorm(12L));
dt2 <- data.table(id=13:18,expand.grid(V1=1:2,V2=1:3),blah2=rnorm(6L));
dt1;
##     id V1 V2      blah1
##  1:  1  1  1 -0.6264538
##  2:  2  2  1  0.1836433
##  3:  3  3  1 -0.8356286
##  4:  4  1  2  1.5952808
##  5:  5  2  2  0.3295078
##  6:  6  3  2 -0.8204684
##  7:  7  1  3  0.4874291
##  8:  8  2  3  0.7383247
##  9:  9  3  3  0.5757814
## 10: 10  1  4 -0.3053884
## 11: 11  2  4  1.5117812
## 12: 12  3  4  0.3898432
dt2;
##    id V1 V2       blah2
## 1: 13  1  1 -0.62124058
## 2: 14  2  1 -2.21469989
## 3: 15  1  2  1.12493092
## 4: 16  2  2 -0.04493361
## 5: 17  1  3 -0.01619026
## 6: 18  2  3  0.94383621
key <- paste0('V',1:2);
dt1[dt2,on=key,id:=i.id];
dt1;
##     id V1 V2      blah1
##  1: 13  1  1 -0.6264538
##  2: 14  2  1  0.1836433
##  3:  3  3  1 -0.8356286
##  4: 15  1  2  1.5952808
##  5: 16  2  2  0.3295078
##  6:  6  3  2 -0.8204684
##  7: 17  1  3  0.4874291
##  8: 18  2  3  0.7383247
##  9:  9  3  3  0.5757814
## 10: 10  1  4 -0.3053884
## 11: 11  2  4  1.5117812
## 12: 12  3  4  0.3898432
```

Comment: Many thanks for speedy and detailed reply! And if there some mismatches and I care only about all matches from the second table, I should use all.y=T, right? And all mismatches will be marked as NA?

Comment: Hi @Mathemilda. It seems we've found a hole in data.table's functionality. I can't find any way of using the `dt1[dt2]` index-join syntax to achieve a left join, which is what we need here. The `merge.data.table()` function supports the `all.y` parameter, but it doesn't support a `j` parameter for specifying the assignment, so we can't use that. The `nomatch` parameter of the indexing function only supports changing from right join (`nomatch=NA`, which is the default) to inner join (`nomatch=0`). There's no way to replace mismatches with NA in the same index-join-assignment.

Comment: A workaround is to effectively nullify the entire `id` column *prior* to running the index-join-assignment operation, and then only matching rows will be set from `dt2`. The remainder would be left as NA. IOW, run `dt1$id <- NA;` before running the index-join-assignment.

Comment: I just asked a question about this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195219/is-it-possible-to-use-the-data-table-index-join-assignment-idiom-to-do-a-left-jo.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort!