# Is it possible to use the data.table index-join-assignment idiom to do a left join and assign NAs in the non-matching rows of i to x?

Tags: r, data.table, left-join, assign

Yesterday I gave this answer: [Matching Data Tables by five columns to change a value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176643/matching-data-tables-by-five-columns-to-change-a-value-in-another-column/39176820#39176820).

In the comments, the OP asked if we could effectively achieve a left join of the two tables and thereby get the NAs that would result in the right table to be assigned to the left table. It seems to me that data.table does not provide any means of doing this.

Here's the example case I used in that question:

```
set.seed(1L);
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:12,expand.grid(V1=1:3,V2=1:4),blah1=rnorm(12L));
dt2 <- data.table(id=13:18,expand.grid(V1=1:2,V2=1:3),blah2=rnorm(6L));
dt1;
##     id V1 V2      blah1
##  1:  1  1  1 -0.6264538
##  2:  2  2  1  0.1836433
##  3:  3  3  1 -0.8356286
##  4:  4  1  2  1.5952808
##  5:  5  2  2  0.3295078
##  6:  6  3  2 -0.8204684
##  7:  7  1  3  0.4874291
##  8:  8  2  3  0.7383247
##  9:  9  3  3  0.5757814
## 10: 10  1  4 -0.3053884
## 11: 11  2  4  1.5117812
## 12: 12  3  4  0.3898432
dt2;
##    id V1 V2       blah2
## 1: 13  1  1 -0.62124058
## 2: 14  2  1 -2.21469989
## 3: 15  1  2  1.12493092
## 4: 16  2  2 -0.04493361
## 5: 17  1  3 -0.01619026
## 6: 18  2  3  0.94383621
key <- paste0('V',1:2);
```

And here's the solution I gave which does *not* get NAs for non-matching rows:

```
dt1[dt2,on=key,id:=i.id];
dt1;
##     id V1 V2      blah1
##  1: 13  1  1 -0.6264538
##  2: 14  2  1  0.1836433
##  3:  3  3  1 -0.8356286
##  4: 15  1  2  1.5952808
##  5: 16  2  2  0.3295078
##  6:  6  3  2 -0.8204684
##  7: 17  1  3  0.4874291
##  8: 18  2  3  0.7383247
##  9:  9  3  3  0.5757814
## 10: 10  1  4 -0.3053884
## 11: 11  2  4  1.5117812
## 12: 12  3  4  0.3898432
```

What we need is for the `id` values 12 and under that remain in `dt1` to be replaced with NAs (*not* because they are 12 and under, and *not* because those id values are missing from `dt2`, but because the join on the `key` columns, namely `V1` and `V2`, does not result in a match for those rows in `dt1` against `dt2`).

As I said in the comments of that question, a workaround is to preassign `dt1$id` to all NAs, and then run the index-join-assignment. Hence, this is the expected output:

```
dt1$id <- NA;
dt1[dt2,on=key,id:=i.id];
dt1;
##     id V1 V2      blah1
##  1: 13  1  1 -0.6264538
##  2: 14  2  1  0.1836433
##  3: NA  3  1 -0.8356286
##  4: 15  1  2  1.5952808
##  5: 16  2  2  0.3295078
##  6: NA  3  2 -0.8204684
##  7: 17  1  3  0.4874291
##  8: 18  2  3  0.7383247
##  9: NA  3  3  0.5757814
## 10: NA  1  4 -0.3053884
## 11: NA  2  4  1.5117812
## 12: NA  3  4  0.3898432
```

I think the workaround is ok, but I'm not sure why data.table doesn't seem to be capable of this functionality in one shot with an index-join-assign operation. The following are three dead-ends I explored:

**1:** `nomatch`

data.table provides a `nomatch` argument which looks a little bit like the `all`, `all.x`, and `all.y` arguments of `merge()`. This is actually a very limited argument; it only allows changing from a right join (`nomatch=NA`, the default) to an inner join (`nomatch=0`). We cannot achieve a left join with it.

**2:** flip `dt1` and `dt2`

Since `dt1[dt2]` is a right join, we can just flip it, meaning `dt2[dt1]`, to achieve the corresponding left join.

This will not work either because we need to use the `:=` in-place assignment syntax in the `j` argument to assign into `dt1`, and under the flipped call, we'll instead be assigning to `dt2`. I tried assigning to `i.id` under the flipped command, but it didn't affect the original `dt1`.

**3:** use `merge.data.table()`

We can call `merge.data.table()` with the `all.x=T` argument to achieve a left join. The problem now is that `merge.data.table()` has no `j` argument, and it simply provides no means of assigning in-place a column of the left (or right) table.

---

So, is it possible to perform this operation at all using data.table? And if so, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIU you just want to lookup `id` column from `dt2` to `dt1`. Original `id` variable in `dt1` seems to be unrelated to whole process as you join on `V1,V2` and you don't want to have `dt1$id` values in the result. So technically correct way to address it is to not use that column at all.

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:12,expand.grid(V1=1:3,V2=1:4),blah1=rnorm(12L));
dt2 <- data.table(id=13:18,expand.grid(V1=1:2,V2=1:3),blah2=rnorm(6L));
on = paste0("V",1:2) # I rename to `on` to not mask `key` function
dt1[,id:=NULL
    ][dt2,on=on,id:=i.id
      ][]
#  V1 V2      blah1 id
# 1:  1  1 -0.6264538 13
# 2:  2  1  0.1836433 14
# 3:  3  1 -0.8356286 NA
# 4:  1  2  1.5952808 15
# 5:  2  2  0.3295078 16
# 6:  3  2 -0.8204684 NA
# 7:  1  3  0.4874291 17
# 8:  2  3  0.7383247 18
# 9:  3  3  0.5757814 NA
#10:  1  4 -0.3053884 NA
#11:  2  4  1.5117812 NA
#12:  3  4  0.3898432 NA
```

Aside from the question...
- you don't have to use `;` at the end of line if there is only single expression to evaluate
- use `dt1[, id := NA_integer_]` instead of `dt1$id <- NA`
- use `set.seed` when providing code with `rnorm` and other randomness related calls

Comment: Minor: if you want the column order to be preserved, use `id := NA` instead of `id := NULL`.

Comment: Excellent answer. It never occurred to me that the original `id` column in `dt1` is irrelevant to the construction of the new `id` column. I suppose there can *never* be a benefit to using a left join with the index-join-assignment idiom, because non-matching rows should either be left alone (achievable with an inner/right join), or their replacement values can be determined independently of the previous values, which is achievable by entirely rebuilding the column (resulting in NAs) or assigning the desired replacement value prior to the index-join-assignment operation.